# Entity Framework Code First with Fluent API Concurrency `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` Not Raising

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concurrency

I am trying to handle concurrency using entity framework 6. My entity looks like below;

```
public partial class Group : BaseEntity
{
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    ...............
}
```

Mapping

```
public partial class GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("CRM_Sales_Group");
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        //tried like this too -> this.Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
        this.Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken().IsRowVersion();
    }
```

The generic repository update method doesn't modify the state, it just validates and then i call the savechanges();

```
            public virtual void Update(T entity)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (entity == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    var msg = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            msg += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, 

validationError.ErrorMessage);

                    var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
                    //Debug.WriteLine(fail.Message, fail);
                    throw fail;
                }
            }
        }
       _groupRepository.Update(group);
```

And in the Razor view;

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion)
```

Still no luck at catching it in controller

```
        public ActionResult Edit(GroupModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    group = model.ToEntity(group);
                    _groupService.UpdateGroup(group);

                    ContainerResolver.Resolve<IDbContext>().SaveChanges();

                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**What am i really missing ?**

#### Update 1

Well i am trying to follow the official documentation. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. I tried to edit the same record in two different tabs of the browser and updated the one record and the same record in another tab update. The rowversion value is comming different but the exception isn't firing.

Comment: Can you give a complete picture of both updates to the database, what are you doing exactly? EF Optimistic concurrency mechanism makes sure that you do not update the db when you have 'old data'.

Comment: Is the dbcontext that is resolved in the controller-method the same instance as the one that is used in the repositories?

Comment: well i am trying to follow the official documentation. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. I tried to edit the same record in two different tabs of the browser and updated the one record and the same record in another tab update. The rowversion value is comming different but the exception isn't firing.

Comment: Am no EF expert and therefore could just be missing it in the above - where is the `where` clause for `rowversion`?

Comment: yes, dbcontext scope is per life cycle. it works with transaction. i have hide the code for it. there is alot of plumbing code.

Comment: @EdSF, there is no where code mention in the official docs. see my updated question

Comment: Yes, there is: `db.Entry(departmentToUpdate).OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = rowVersion;`

Comment: Add SQL logging to your dbcontext to see the SQL that is generated when you `SaveChanges`.  You can do this with a line similar to this: `context.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);`. (You can make it point to something else if the Console is not appropriate) Then edit your post with the SQL that you see.  It will help.

Comment: trying your solutions now

Comment: Do you have your `GroupMap` class registered somewhere in a `DbModelBuilder` class?

Comment: yes coz its working. there is no problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was missing

```
db.Entry(departmentToUpdate).OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = rowVersion;
```

Now its working :)